# SQL Server full text search query takes way too long to execute

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, full-text-search

I've got query snippet as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM CONTAINSTABLE(dbo.Analysis, *, 'FORMSOF(FREETEXT, "historic year-on-year exchange rates forecast year-on-year exchange rates")');
```

I'm running it on SQL Server 2014.

However it executes forever, so I just give up and cancel it.

- If I remove words `year-on-year` it works just fine.
- FTCatalog was rebuilt - didn't help.

This has been driving me crazy for a while now.
I dont't have a lot of experience with FTS searches, but this just doesn't make any sense.

Please advice how to make it work or where I should start looking at.

Comment: Punctuation marks are considered word breaks in full text searches, and they are not stored in the full text database. I suspect it's taking so long because you are searching for forms of "year" and "on" and getting a lot of matches. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/200043. I will leave this as a comment rather than an answer as I don't have a solution for how you should get it working.

Comment: it's probably returning every row that includes the word "on", which is likely a lot. Make "on" a stopword, or change "year-on-year" to "yoy" or similar in both the index and the query (using synonyms)

Answer (score 2):

In place of your query, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Analysis 
where FREETEXT(dbo.Analysis, 'historic year-on-year exchange rates forecast
yearon-year exchange rates');
```

or this:

```
SELECT * FROM  dbo.Analysis 
where CONTAINS(dbo.Analysis, "historic year-on-year exchange rates forecast
year-on-year exchange rates");
```

Also, the hyphens may be causing problems.  Try:

> year on year

or

> yearonyear

in place of the hyphens.

Lastly, did you build and enable a stop list?

Comment: I've tried removing hyphens, but then there were no results, unfortunately. Although it was running instantly. There were more phrases that were killing my query and I didn't manage to realise why.